# Scenarios where Clients application needs to rebuild

Tags: visual-c++, com, atl

i need to know the scenarios wherein the client application needs to rebuild, i have few , if there are any other scenarios let me know.

1) i add a new Interface into an existing CoClass and its method build the new dll and copy it in the client machine, is there any need for the client application to rebuild.

2) i add a new CoClass and Interface and Methods to an exisiing DLL project build the new dll and copy it in the client machine, is there any need for the client application to rebuild.

so my question is , is there any need for the old clients to rebuild, assuming that they will not need the new functionality?

Note: All clients applications new and old are .NET client, so there is a .NET Interop layer( which anyhow needs to change) but what about the old clients

appreciate your help

Regards

Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume late binding is the client's preferred way to use the COM server.  Any change to an existing interface requires the interface to get a different IID.  A very important DLL Hell countermeasure.  Such a change includes inserting or removing a method as well as altering any of the arguments of an existing method.  A change in the IID requires the client to be rebuilt so it knows to use the new IID.

Changes that do not break a client:

- appending a method to the end of an interface.  It is risky to not change the IID in such a case but it the change is forward compatible.  Since the client doesn't yet know that the method exists.  However, as soon as it is changed to take advantage of the method, it is no longer backwards compatible.  It will crash badly if it ever runs with an older version of your COM server and uses early binding.  Only contemplate this if you can tightly control deployment of both the server and the client, that is not very common.  Changing the IID is strongly recommended.
- adding an interface to a coclass.  That's forward compatible, again the client doesn't yet know about the new interface.  Until it is modified to take advantage of it.  Running with an old version provides a reasonable diagnostic, E_NOINTERFACE.
- adding a new coclass.  Forward compatible just as the previous bullet.  Running with an old version generates the REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG diagnostic.

So the two bullets you gave are in fact *not* reasons to have to recompile the client.